# TypeError: Utils is not a constructor

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, datetimepicker, date-fns, muipickersutilsprovider

I am using `MuiPickersUtilsProvider` from `@material-ui/pickers@` `v-3.2.10`

and using like followings:

```
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns'
import { DateTimePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers'

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                <DateTimePicker .../>
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

It works on UI but while running test case it throws error as follows:

> TypeError: Utils is not a constructor

But as soon as I use `import * as DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns'` our test case works but same error comes on UI,

And When I use `import {default as DateFnsUtils} from '@date-io/date-fns'` our test case works but same error comes on both place(UI and test case)

I found similar discussion on below link but no help

[material-ui-pickers/issues/805](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/805)

```
// setup file
var enzyme = require('enzyme');
var Adapter = require('enzyme-adapter-react-16');
require('jest-canvas-mock')
enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

crypto = require('@trust/webcrypto')

// fetch undefined
const fetchPolifill = require('whatwg-fetch')
global.fetch = fetchPolifill.fetch
global.Request = fetchPolifill.Request
global.Headers = fetchPolifill.Headers
global.Response = fetchPolifill.Response

function noOp () { }
if (typeof window.URL.createObjectURL === 'undefined') {
  Object.defineProperty(window.URL, 'createObjectURL', { value: noOp})
}
```

Comment: Are you also using Typescript for building code?

Comment: Can you share your jest configuration too?

Comment: added configs @tmhao2005

Comment: yes I'm using Typescript

Comment: Nope. I meant the jest configuration to get to know how you transform your code in jest.

Comment: I also meat did you use `ts-jest`?

Comment: it is working for all(1000+) other test cases, except this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221216/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-akhilesh-kumar).

Comment: It looks like your case is to have 2 tsconfig files one for test one for build but with two `esModuleInterop` different values. The value in the test is false. Can you have a look again and give me the info?

Comment: Both are using same tsconfig.ts, `esModuleInterop` is false in both.

Comment: I think I know what is the issue. As long as you can confirm that you currently use `ts-jest` as transformer for your `jest`?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and I resolved by following code,

```
"<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>"


import React, { useState } from 'react'
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, KeyboardDatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';

const ProblemStatement = () => {
 const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date('2014-08-18T21:11:54'))
    const handleDateChange = (date) => {
        setSelectedDate(date)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            ProblemStatement
            <h2>datepicker</h2>
            //this one
            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                <KeyboardDatePicker
                    margin="normal"
                    id="date-picker-dialog"
                    label="Date picker dialog"
                    format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                    value={selectedDate}
                    onChange={handleDateChange}
                    KeyboardButtonProps={{
                        'aria-label': 'change date',
                    }}
                />
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>


        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when using `LocalizationProvider` in order to use `DatePicker` component of **mui**.
In my case, the problem was related to a typo in `dateAdapter` prop. I passed `dataAdapter={AdapterDateFns}` instead of `dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}`. The problem is solved after fixing the typo:

```
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';

export default function App() {

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <Main />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: This should be rated as the correct answer.